# Customize form_for collection_check_boxes view result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, form-for

Acording to the app styles, checkboxes with form_for go as following:

```
%label
  Show featured data?
  = f.check_box :on_display
  %i
```

Now on a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship, i need to use `collection_check_boxes` `form_for` helper, and need to edit for show every results in the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved!**

> Here a [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768006/rails-3-has-and-belongs-to-many-creates-checkboxes-in-view) for solve

`collection_check_boxes` was not the way, and done with
the following code:

```
- Team.all.each do |t|
            %label
              ="Available on #{t.name}"
              = check_box_tag '[team_ids][]', t.id
              %i
```